# Why is using innerHTML to append a large number of elements to the DOM slower than JQuery's append() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a vanilla JavaScript function to test appending large numbers of elements to the DOM:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var blah;
var div = document.getElementById("me");
for (i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    div.innerHTML += "<div>" + i + "</div>";//Simply add to div.
}
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
alert('Execution time: ' + time);
```

#### Results:

```
         Chrome           IE10
         ------           -----  
Vanilla      39             130  (seconds)
```

#### JQuery:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    $("#me").append("<div>" + i + "</div>");//Now using append instead.
}
```

#### Results

```
         Chrome           IE10
         ------           -----  
Vanilla   39000         130,000  (milliseconds) 
JQuery      260            1300  (milliseconds)
```

**NB**: It didn't seem to have any impact on performance if I used the `$("#me")` selector or passed in `$(div)`

#### Vanilla with `AppendChild`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");//Now create an element and append it.
    el.innerHTML = i;
    div.appendChild(el);
}
```

```
             Chrome           IE10
             ------           -----  
Vanilla       39000         130,000  (ms)   
JQuery          260            1300  (ms) 
AppendChild      30             240  (ms)
```

To my huge surprise this was by far the fastest, most performant. On Chrome it takes a whopping 30ms or so, and on IE it takes around 240ms.

You can play with all the variations here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VC5R/)

I know there could be many other variations to test, but what is jQuery doing behind the scenes to make it's `.append()` so much faster than native JS `innerHTML +=` and why is creating a new element and appending it even faster?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for `append`? And are you sure you're comparing apples to apples?  The real questions are: Are you using the right function to locate an element quickly; are you caching that result once you find it, are those functions (`innerHTML`) doing what you think they're doing (and doing the same thing) (and no more) and What's the fastest way to append HTML to the DOM (there may be more than one way!).

Comment: `append` is doing _HTML String_ to _#document_fragment_ then into _DOM_ whereas `innerHTML` is re-parsing that entire section of _DOM_ every time. The native _DOM_ methods using `createElement` are faster than `append` because it's not having to parse any _HTML_ (until you set the _innerHTML_ of that again)

Comment: jQuery append !== innerHTML ... jQuery html() == innerHTML

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Most guides that list jQuery pure JS equivalent functions list `innerHTML +=` as an equivalent to `.append()`. Is this incorrect?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/here-we-go-again

Comment: Malcoda: That is incorrect, indeed. It may work the same from the user's point of view (Add string to DOM), behind the scenes, it's a lot more efficient, as @PaulS. explained.

Comment: @Malcoda on top of Cerbrus' comment, `innerHTML` will also remove event handlers registered to the content that gets re-parsed

Comment: @PaulS. Damn, Today I learned yet another reason why `innerHTML` is evil.

Comment: @PaulS. Except [inline event handlers](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Hnh/), but who uses those, right? :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol On top of my rejection that inline event handlers exist, I also refuse to accept that _attributes_ can have mixed case or that `alert` is a native function in _JavaScript_ implementations.</dream world>

Comment: @PaulS. Ah, you reject our reality and substitute your own, do you? :p But yeah, basically everything's wrong with that JSFiddle there, but it was mainly to show that even code made entirely of hax can sometimes work XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you [do things right](http://jsperf.com/here-we-go-again), you can pretty much double your "best" result.

Native DOM methods are *always* faster than their jQuery alternatives. However, `.innerHTML` is not ideal.

When you use `.innerHTML += ...`, here's what happens:

1. Build an HTML representation of the entire DOM that current exists
2. Append your new string to it
3. Parse the result and create a whole new DOM tree from it
4. Put the new stuff in place of the old stuff

The native methods are significantly less work ;)

It should also be noted that `innerHTML += ...` *completely nukes the DOM*, meaning any references to the old elements are lost and in particular event handlers are not kept (unless you used inline event handlers, which you shouldn't be)

Comment: _"(unless you used inline event handlers, which you shouldn't be)"_ Oh the irony. To work around a "bug" in code you shouldn't use, you'd have to write more code you really shouldn't use.

Comment: @Cerbrus Basically yeah XD And even I fall prey to the "bug" sometimes. I used `container.innerHTML = ""` to empty an element before re-populating it, then tried to re-append an element that I had a reference to, only to find it empty in IE because clearing an element in that way also detaches children!

Comment: Even if the HTML is concatenated into a single string, then assigned as the innerHTML, the `+=` operator is notoriously slow in some browsers and simply changing to `markup = markup + '...'` makes a significant difference (of course the difference may be insignificant in some hosts and not in others).

Answer (score 5):

Behind the scenes, [jQuery is using document fragments](https://github.com/private-face/jquery/blob/87e1569677e1e5fe9e8e9f4d7da3ecd5a47f708d/src/manipulation.js#L468), which perform much better than straight manipulation of the document. [John Resig discussed document fragments' superior performance in 2008](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/), which should give you a solid explanation about what jQuery is doing and why.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it would be much more efficient if you calculated everything you wished to append beforehand, then append that - minimize the DOM manipulation required.  eg:

```
var toAppend = "";
for (i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
   toAppend += "<div>" + i + "</div>";
}
div.append(toAppend)
```

If you're wanting them to be nested, you could make it recursive, or come up with some other solution.  either way, I believe string manipulation will always be faster than DOM manipulation

Comment: That is indeed correct, "less `innerHTML` calls" is better, but "no `innerHTML` calls" is best ;)