# Last inserted element flash color

Tags: javascript, css

I have a real time feed that brings in things every few seconds. I want to highlight newly entered information so that people monitoring the feed can see something changed.

Right now every element flashes when the animation is called. How do I make it so that only the last inserted element is highlighted?

**Must use pure javascript and no plugins.**

```js
var doc = document.getElementById('results');

function next(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.innerHTML = '<p>Hi ' + i + '<p>' + doc.innerHTML;
    next(++i);
  }, 1000);
}
next(1);
```

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: red
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

p {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

## EDIT

I can use first-child, but if I have a bulk update it doesn't select all of them.

```js
var doc = document.getElementById('results');

function next(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.innerHTML = '<p>Hi1 ' + i + '<p>'+'<p>Hs2 ' + i + '<p>' + doc.innerHTML;
    next(++i);
  }, 1000);
}
next(1);
```

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: red
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

p:first-child {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Comment: If all of your added elements follow a certain structure, you could use the [last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/) selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo selector.

**Edit**: if you want to insert and flash in bulk, the easiest way is to wrap the paragraphs in a `div` with a class, and use the `first-of-type` selector on the `div` instead of on `p`.

```js
var doc = document.getElementById('results');

function next(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.innerHTML = '<div class="inserted"><p>Hi1 ' + i + '<p>'+'<p>Hs2 ' + i + '<p></div>' + doc.innerHTML;
    next(++i);
  }, 1000);
}
next(1);
```

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: red
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

.inserted:first-of-type {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Comment: I can use first child, but I came into the problem with bulk updates. I edited my answer to represent to following. Thank you this work, but not completely what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I have to ask, are you using innerHtml on purpose? It's horribly inefficient (reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244104/why-is-using-innerhtml-to-append-a-large-number-of-elements-to-the-dom-slower-th)). You'd be better off creating DOM elements and appending them to your container. That would also allow you to have a much more generic solution.

It will also allow you to use a selector such as a class for your highlight, and bulk updates will continue to work.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kun08xe/5/)

I did change it to only run 10 times:

HTML

```
<div id="results">
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: red
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

.child {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

JS

```
var doc = document.getElementById('results');

function next(i) {
    if(i < 10) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "child";
    div.textContent = "Hi " + i;
    doc.insertBefore(div, doc.firstChild);
    next(++i);
  }, 1000);
  }
}
next(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CSS` pseudo selector for if the last element is always prepended inside `#results`.

```
p:first-child {
    animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uz2weL3z/

---

If you want to always target the **last inserted** then use `JavaScript` as such:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doc.innerHTML = '<p class="last">Hi ' + i + '<p>' + doc.innerHTML;
    setTimeout(function() {
        for(var j=0; j<els.length; j++) {
            els[j].className = "";
        }
    }, 1000);

    next(++i);
}, 1000);
```

**Timeout of 1 sec because your animation is 1 sec**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uz2weL3z/1/